# Не проходит оплата в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telebot

```
bot.send_invoice(
            chat_id=message.chat.id,
            title='Подписка',
            description='Подписка',
            invoice_payload='Подписка',
            provider_token=youkassa_token,
            currency='RUB',
            start_parameter='Подписка',
            prices=[types.LabeledPrice(label='Working Time Machine', amount=5750), types.LabeledPrice('Gift wrapping', 5068)]
            )
```

Не знаю что у меня не правильно, но ошибка "rices=types.LabeledPrice({'label':"Руб",'amount':5068})
TypeError: LabeledPrice.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'"

Comment: Класс `LabeledPrice` принимает два аргумента, а вы передаёте всего один (да и тот неправильный, потому что первый аргумент должен быть строкой, а не словарём)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как надо

Comment: Буду очень благодарен

Comment: В [примерах pytelegrambotapi](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/payments_example.py) можно посмотреть